# trying to do a drop down list which changes the button but as soon as i upload it to website it doesn't work but works offline

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a drop-down list that changes the button, but as soon as I upload it to the website it doesn't work, what I am wanting it to do is when an option is selected then the 'book now' button pops up with a bit of extra text and then continue to the new website. It completely works when I use the preview in browser from dreamweaver however when I upload to website and I select any of the options, the button doesn't appear

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/outside-socket')
    //.....................^.......
    {
      $("#business").show();
      $("#business_new").hide();
      $("#business1").hide();
      $("#business2").hide();
      $("#business3").hide();

    } else if (this.value == 'https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/switchsocket-front-replacement') {
      $("#business").hide();
      $("#business_new").show();
      $("#business1").hide();
      $("#business2").hide();
      $("#business3").hide();

    } else if (this.value == 'https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/booking') {
      $("#business").hide();
      $("#business_new").hide();
      $("#business1").show();
      $("#business2").hide();
      $("#business3").hide();

    } else if (this.value == 'https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/ffb-booking-2') {
      $("#business").hide();
      $("#business_new").hide();
      $("#business1").hide();
      $("#business2").show();
      $("#business3").hide();

    } else if (this.value == 'https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/booking') {
      $("#business").hide();
      $("#business_new").hide();
      $("#business1").hide();
      $("#business2").hide();
      $("#business3").show();


    } else {
      $("#business").hide();

    }
  });
});

function redirectToMyPage() {
  optionSelected = document.getElementById('purpose').value;
  //redirec to my url
  window.location.replace(optionSelected);

}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<select id='purpose'>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select booking option</option>
  <option value="https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/outside-socket"> Outside socket </option>
  <option value="https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/switchsocket-front-replacement">Socket face replacement </option>
  <option value="https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/booking2">2 or socket face replacements</option>
  <option value="https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/ffb-booking-2">Extra socket in white</option>
  <option value="https://tripped-electrical.appointlet.com/s/booking">2 or more extra sockets in white</option>
</select>

<div style='display:none;' id='business'> <br/>&nbsp;
  <button id="button1" onclick="redirectToMyPage();">Book now</button>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='business_new'> <br/>&nbsp;
  <button id="button1" onclick="redirectToMyPage();">Book now</button>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='business1'> <br/>&nbsp;
  <button id="button1" onclick="redirectToMyPage();">Book now</button>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='business2'> <br/>&nbsp;
  <button id="button1" onclick="redirectToMyPage();">Book now</button>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='business3'> <br/>&nbsp;
  <button id="button1" onclick="redirectToMyPage();">Book now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why so many spaces between `-                        e` ?

Comment: first time using this and i clicked too many when trying to add the html

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using - or forced to use - such an antiquated version of jQuery? Your problem-description is "*it doesn't work*," which is hard to understand when we have no idea how your function is supposed to work; so: what do you expect your code to do? What happens, or doesn't happen, instead? Please look at "[ask]" for guidance as to what we expect in questions here.

Comment: not at all, I was simply trying to follow some guides off here and put it together. i will reword the question